# Mysql - How can I select rows based on two criterias

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this query, to select all the rows that have status = 1:

```
SELECT
acc.id,
acc.user_id,
acc.type,
acc.account,
acc.`status`,
acc.paid,
acc.`password`, CAST(AES_DECRYPT( BASE64_DECODE( `password` ), 'encryption-key') AS CHAR)
FROM acc

WHERE status = status = '1'
```

However, it returns all the tables, it does't select only the rows that have status = 1

It's probably a syntax error. I do need this

```
`acc.`password`, CAST(AES_DECRYPT( BASE64_DECODE( `password` ), 'encryption-key') AS CHAR)`
```

part so I can decrypt the passwords.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `WHERE status = status = '1'`?

Comment: I want to select only the rows that have status = 1. Did I do something dumb?

Comment: @juergend  I see the error now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to append `acc.` to all the fields given you're only retrieving data from one table.
- You had and extra status attached to your condition

Should be:

```
SELECT `id`,
       `user_id`,
       `type`,
       `account`,
       `status`,
       `paid`,
       `password`, 
       CAST(AES_DECRYPT(BASE64_DECODE(`password`),'encryption-key') AS CHAR)
  FROM acc
 WHERE status = '1'
```